# In qnetworkauth of QT framework, how to not open redirect uri in browser after authentication done

Tags: authorization, google-oauth, qt5, qtnetwork, redirect-uri

I am developing desktop application using oauth2 protocol of qnetworkauth. The authentication with authorization server is quite good. But after authentication done, the loopback redirect uri 127.0.0.1:PORT is open in browser with the text: "Callback received. Feel free to close this page.". I understand that application create http server listening authorization server to receive code and tokens. The thing is my customer don't want the redirect uri being opened in browser since it looks meaningless and confused.
However I read qnetworkauth code and don't see any snippet of code that open that redirect uri in browser and suspect that authorization server is the one to do that.
Can anyone confirm with me if qnetworkauth open it? If it is the case, how and where to disable it? Thank you very much.

Use qnetworkauth of qt5 to archive oauth2 for windows application, set redirect uri 127.0.0.1:8888
Expectation: loopback uri is not opened in browser
Actually: loopback uri is opened after authentication done